# How to set methods visible only for classes derived on different class?

Tags: c++

I'm creating little GUI for my OpenGL game. I've got two base classes `Widget` and `Container`. `Widget` class has methods like `setPosition(x,y)`, `setSize(w,h)`,... These methods should be visible only for classes derived from `Container`.

**Edit:** I can do it with friend and wrapper methods, but I'd like to do it without wrappers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to only containers to be able to position objects.

Comment: protected + friend + protected wrapper ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I can do it with wrapper. But i'm looking for nicer solution.

Comment: I don't think C++ has a way to specify this other than the friend mechanism.  You could separate your drawing code from the model (which would have the setters) then make the model protected and friendly...

Comment: Why do you want to limit those functions to objects derived from container? Do you want to provide an interface just for that? (you could make inheritance from that interface private, declare `Container` a friend and provide a function in `Container` that takes a `Widget` and returns the `Drawable` interface...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's already posted as answer ;) (similar solution)

Comment: @Miro: Is it? I have read the three answers (twice) and I don't understand the same thing... What I suggested was not adding forwarding for all member functions, but just a single operation in `Container` that would yield a richer `Widget` interface that includes those member functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the suggestion was not clear from the comment, you can consider creating an interface with that subset of the methods and use private inheritance in `Widget`. Then use a protected (a single operation) in `Container` that would obtain that private interface for classes derived from it:

```
struct Drawable {    // choose a better name
  virtual void setPosition( int x, int y );
  virtual void setSize( int w, int h );
  virtual ~Drawable() {}
};
class Widget : private Drawable {
   friend class Container;
};
class Container {
protected:
    Drawable& getDrawable( Widget& w ) { return w; };
};
class MyContainer : public Container {
   void changeSize( Widget & w ) {
      getDrawable(w).setSize(10,20);
   }
};
```

The main difference with the forwarding options is that this scales better with the number of functions and is more maintainable (no need to update N-forwarders, just the accessor to the proper interface).

From a high level design point of view, a `Widget` is not `Drawable` in general, it is only `Drawable` from the context of `Widget` or `Container`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid of writing this answer because it seems too obvious, but couldn't you just make `setPosition(x,y)` and `setSize(w,h)` members of `Container`?

or if there's some sort of unknown complexity could you make a `WidgetContainer` as a base class and put those methods in that class?

Comment: Yes, it's obvious and it seems to be only one solution. I can't make them together because `Container` doesn't need to be also `Widget`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is one of those "what can I do that should make another programmer feel dirty when they do it wrong" sort of situations: it's not well handled by the language, so you don't want to be overly restrictive in your code, because that tends to make things confusing. Friend-container-delegate setups will, in my opinion, just confuse people trying to figure out your code in everyday "how does this work" situations. You want to make it harder to abuse your code in "I need to hack on this" situations.

What I would do is perhaps something as simple as document well and call the (public) functions `_setPosition` and `_setSize`. The underscore will (hopefully) make other programmers go, "wha???" and read your documentation - which will explain exactly why it's a very bad idea for non-`Container`s to call those functions.

It's slightly ugly, but that's the *point*. I would certainly feel dirty calling `rect._setPosition` without understanding what's going on. It's a psychological solution, but used a lot in other languages where the access protection facilities are lacking - like Javascript - so is not so unusual as to be hideously ugly. Or at least, not more hideously ugly than trying to specify your requirements in the features of the language :)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. But David provided little bit better solution ;)